# ssrs sub-report does not show all that is contain in sub page

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

i am creating sub-report ssrs. [see the pictures below at the red square]

[Attachment A - This will be the subreport to the Allowance Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s9jR.png)

[This is when the report looks like after being attached to the Allowance Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL15B.png)

Please someone explain it to me and help me resolve this. Why when it is attached to the Allowance report, the word in subreport **(Kembaran A & Terhad)** is not appearing?

I've been adjusting the height. But still not appearing. This is my first time doing ssrs. and this report was generated from the previous programmer which i do not who.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information, my guess is that the missing text is in the header of the sub-report.

Headers and footers are not displayed in subreports

If you remove the header and add the information to the body of the report, you should be right...

Comment: owh i see. Thank you! i've delete the header and do it along with the data.

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answer if this helped you solve your problem